No initializer set for given class
I have been working on a notice app based on the Inventory App(Tutorial App that Android Studio provides in their CodeLab). I tried to add a searchbar in Homescreen so that the users can search items with keywords in their names.
I made no changes to the original ViewModels and Screens except adding the SearchBar on HomeScreen. All the original functions work well. When I input the searchQuery and tapped search on the simulator, the App crashed. I checked the info in logcat. It popped the problem: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:No initializer set for given class com.example.inventory.ui.searchResultScreen.SearchResultViewModel. Really have no clue what I did wrong.

 

package com.example.inventory.ui.searchResultScreen

import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.inventory.data.Item
import com.example.inventory.data.ItemsRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharingStarted
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.filterNotNull
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.stateIn

/**
 * ViewModel to retrieve all items in the Room database.
 */
class SearchResultViewModel(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle, itemsRepository: ItemsRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val searchQuery: String = checkNotNull(savedStateHandle[SearchResultDestination.searchQueryArg])

    /**
     * Holds searchResult ui state. The list of items are retrieved from [ItemsRepository] and mapped to
     * [SearchResultUiState]
     */
    val searchResultUiState: StateFlow<SearchResultUiState> =
        itemsRepository.searchItemsStream(searchQuery)
            .filterNotNull()
            .map { SearchResultUiState(it) }
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(TIMEOUT_MILLIS),
                initialValue = SearchResultUiState()
            )

    companion object {
        private const val TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 5_000L
    }
}

/**
 * Ui State for HomeScreen
 */
data class SearchResultUiState(val itemList: List<Item> = listOf())


package com.example.inventory.ui.home

fun HomeScreen(
    navigateToItemEntry: () -> Unit,
    navigateToItemUpdate: (Int) -> Unit,
    navigateToSearchResult: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
)

///
topBar = {
            SearchBar(value = searchQuery, onValueChange = { searchQuery = it }, onSearchClicked = navigateToSearchResult, onClearClick = { searchQuery = "" })
        },
///

@Composable
fun SearchBar(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onClearClick: () -> Unit,
    placeholder: String = "Search",
    icon: ImageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
    onSearchClicked: (String) -> Unit

) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        placeholder = { Text(text = placeholder) },
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(imageVector = icon, contentDescription = "Search icon")
        },
        trailingIcon = if (value.isNotEmpty()) {
            {
                IconButton(onClick = onClearClick) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Clear, contentDescription = "Clear text")
                }
            }
        } else null,
        singleLine = true,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Search),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onSearch = {
            focusManager.clearFocus()
            onSearchClicked("%" + value + "%")

        })
    )
}

fun SearchResultScreen(
    navigateToItemUpdate: (Int) -> Unit,
    navigateBack: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: SearchResultViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
) {
    val searchResultUiState by viewModel.searchResultUiState.collectAsState()
///
}


package com.example.inventory.ui

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory
import androidx.lifecycle.createSavedStateHandle
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.CreationExtras
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.initializer
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.viewModelFactory
import com.example.inventory.InventoryApplication
import com.example.inventory.ui.home.HomeViewModel
import com.example.inventory.ui.item.ItemDetailsViewModel
import com.example.inventory.ui.item.ItemEditViewModel
import com.example.inventory.ui.item.ItemEntryViewModel

/**
 * Provides Factory to create instance of ViewModel for the entire Inventory app
 */
object AppViewModelProvider {
    val Factory = viewModelFactory {
        // Initializer for ItemEditViewModel
        initializer {
            ItemEditViewModel(
                this.createSavedStateHandle(),
                inventoryApplication().container.itemsRepository
            )
        }
        // Initializer for ItemEntryViewModel
        initializer {
            ItemEntryViewModel(inventoryApplication().container.itemsRepository)
        }

        // Initializer for ItemDetailsViewModel
        initializer {
            ItemDetailsViewModel(
                this.createSavedStateHandle(),
                inventoryApplication().container.itemsRepository
            )
        }

        // Initializer for HomeViewModel
        initializer {
            HomeViewModel(inventoryApplication().container.itemsRepository)
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Extension function to queries for [Application] object and returns an instance of
 * [InventoryApplication].
 */
fun CreationExtras.inventoryApplication(): InventoryApplication =
    (this[AndroidViewModelFactory.APPLICATION_KEY] as InventoryApplication)

  
 


Your SearchResultViewModel needs a factory and you need to use that factory in the Composable where you assign it to a parameter.

@Tenfour04 I had the factory in my SearchResultScreen.kt, which was a hard copy of the other factories in other Screen.kts that CodeLab provided in their package(I just changed the reference name.) I updated the code in the question.

Can you add the code defining the factory class itself?

Finally found it. The problem should not be the factory class, cuz this was provided in the original package by CodeLab and the other Screens and ViewModels also implemented it. I think my problem should be in SearchResultViewModel or SearchResultScreen.

Ok After I posted the factory code I found the problem myself. Thanks a lot for the hint!!!
